# output from script into environment variables, bash

Tags: bash, awk, export, environment-variables

I have a script which output that :

```
TAGS    Name    i-1c69afe325    instance    INSTANCE_NAME
```

I want to take "Name" and "INSTANCE_NAME" and make an environment variable with it.

I tried a lot of things and the last was :

```
./test2.sh | awk '{system("export "$2"="$5)}'
```

it did't errored but I don't have any env var.

Any idea ?

PS : if it is important, I try to transform my ec2-tags into environment-variables each time my instance boot.

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: The problem with that awk attempt is that while that might have set the variable in the shell that `system` launched that won't make any difference for the shell that ran the `awk` script (because child processes cannot set variables in parent processes).

Answer (score 1):

Using the information you can find on [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) you come up with something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r tags name i_var instance instance_name; do
  declare "$name"="$instance_name"
done < <(./test2.sh)
```

or with a recent bash

```
while IFS= read -r tags name i_var instance instance_name; do
  printf -v "$name" %s "$instance_name"
done < <(./test2.sh)
```

Comment: I would like to declare something "system wide" not only in the scope of execution.

Comment: Define "system wide". This answer defines the variables for the current shell session. You can add `export "$name"` to these loops to export the variable for child processes run from this shell. If you mean you want this value to persist for all shells (or processes) on this system going forward then you have to set it in the appropriate system locations (and if the value needs to be dynamic then you get to do something like these loop there).